# Access sub accounts onedrive data with admin authentication

Tags: office365, adal, onedrive

We want to pull all our organizations sub-accounts onedrive data,we were able to access only admin onedrive data with OAuth2.0 and Microsoft graph API but didn't find any way to access sub -accounts onedrive data with admin authentication.

Is there any way to do this?.

Please help me on this.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "sub accounts"?

Comment: Under one office 365 business account(admin) we can create multiple users,I have referred those users as sub-accounts.

Comment: Hi Saca, I have resolved this issue by referring to one of the questions answered by you but i have one more question.

Now I am able to access all my organization user's data but what if I want to access any other organization who will get authorization through my app,Is there any way to do this ?